# Get images src's from html code

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an any html code in a variable. For example:

```
var MyHTML = 
'<div>
<ul>
<li><img src="http://aaa.ru/image1.png" /></li>
<li><img src="http://aaa.ru/image2.png" /></li>
<li><img src="http://aaa.ru/image3.png" /></li>
</ul>
</div>';
```

How can i get src all of the images to array (var images = [])?

Comment: I need it for preload images before put html to body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery for this

```
// wrap the HTML into a jQuery object
var $myHTML = $(MyHTML);
// initiate a new empty array
var images = [];
// iterate through all img elements
$myHTML.find('li img').each(function() {
   // push to the array the src attribute
   images.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Also be sure to load the jQuery library if you want to use this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgarray = $('li img').map(function() { return this.src; }).get()
```

Comment: This is jQuery so you need to [include the libraries](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp) in your head.

Comment: Question is somewhat unclear.  Do you want the SRC's in an array before or after the HTML is outputted?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the text, you can use this regex:

```
/src="([^"]+)"/
```

If you are using JavaScript you can do:

```
MyHTML.match(/src="([^"]+)"/g);
```

Comment: Parsing html with regex is not recommended.

Comment: why isn't it recommended?

Comment: See accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You must use REGEX as @Adriien said, as your html are string and you want it pre loading. try this,

```
var MyHTML = 
'<div><ul><li><img src="http://aaa.ru/image1.png" /></li><li><img src="http://aaa.ru/image2.png" /></li><li><img src="http://aaa.ru/image3.png" /></li></ul></div>';
var srcRegex = /<img src="([^"]+)" \/>/ig;

var matches = [];
while (srcRegex.exec(MyHTML)) {
  matches.push(RegExp.$1);
}

//contains all cookie values
console.log(matches);
```

`jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/cwva0b0g/